# Integrating SwiftUI to existing UIKit project causes Xcode Preview not to load

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, swiftui

I have an existing project that uses **UIKit**, however I was required to start integrating SwiftUI, I've followed the following tutorial without luck.
[Include SwiftUI views in existing UIKit application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433826/include-swiftui-views-in-existing-uikit-application)

I have already modified **AppDelegate**, added **SceneDelegate** and updated the **Info.plist** to comply with the new format for SwiftUI projects.

When I compile the app it works, however I need to be able to use the Preview feature. It keeps loading forever and my preview does not show up.

- **Xcode version:** 11.3.1 (11C504)
- **MacOS:** Catalina 10.15.1 (19B88)

Any help would be appreciated!

See image:
https://pasteboard.co/IRl7B5F.png