# How to create a view from an IBaction function in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ibaction

I am having some trouble understanding how I am supposed to create a view from an IBaction function in Xcode.

Does anyone know how I could open the RKViewController from my home page by clicking on a button I have created 'Select Dates'? The IBaction function relating to this button in my code block is 'calendarDisplay'.

The code block for my 'Select Dates' Button:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

@State var startIsPresented = false

var rkManager = RKManager(calendar: Calendar.current, minimumDate: Date(), maximumDate: Date().
addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*730), mode: 1)


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


   func getTextFromDate(date: Date!) -> String {
     let formatter = DateFormatter()
     formatter.locale = .current
     formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy"
     return date == nil ? "" : formatter.string(from: date)
 }

}

@IBAction func calendarDisplay(_ sender: Any) {

**//Not sure what to put here - have tried many times to call the RKViewController but have failed.**


}
}
```

This is the code block which works in another project - I have no idea how to make this work in an @IBaction function, any help would be much appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {

@State var startIsPresented = false

var rkManager = RKManager(calendar: Calendar.current, minimumDate: Date(), maximumDate: Date().
addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*365), mode: 1) //

var body: some View {
    VStack (spacing: 25) {

        Button(action: { self.startIsPresented.toggle() }) {
            VStack {
                Text("Example 2 - Range of Dates Selection").foregroundColor(.blue)
                Text("(end date > start date)").foregroundColor(.blue)
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$startIsPresented, content: {
            RKViewController(isPresented: self.$startIsPresented, rkManager: self.rkManager)})
        VStack {
            Text(self.getTextFromDate(date: self.rkManager.startDate))
            Text(self.getTextFromDate(date: self.rkManager.endDate))
        }

    }
}

func getTextFromDate(date: Date!) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = .current
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy"
    return date == nil ? "" : formatter.string(from: date)
}

}
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to mix `UIKit` (your first view controller) with `SwiftUI` (your `ContentView`).  It's not exactly that simple.  [Here is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433826/include-swiftui-views-in-existing-uikit-application) that might point you in the right direction.

Comment: show your RKViewController code .... what parameter it is taking ? you need to inilize your RKViewController and present it in IBAction function