# How to add SwiftUI form to UIView Controller

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a UIViewController that is presenting a via a function in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return iv
    }()

func configureViewComponents() {
    
    view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Call it as such:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureViewComponents()
}
```

I have a form in a separate file form.swift:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct myForm: View {

@ObservedObject var submission = Submission()

@State var confirmationMessage = ""
@State var showingConfirmation = false


var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Toggle(isOn: $submission.fieldOne ) {
                Text("Field One")
            }
```

I am trying to add it to my UIViewController in the same fashion I add my imageView with `view.addSubview(myForm)` but I am getting the message `cannot convert value of type form to expected argument type UIView.`

How can I present my form in this UIViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `UIHostingController`, like below

```
func configureViewComponents() {

    view.addSubview(imageView)

    let formController = UIHostingController(rootView: myForm())
    if let form = formController.view {
        form.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(form)
        form.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        form.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        form.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        form.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        self.addChild(formController)
    }
}
```

Comment: What about closing the question as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/56433826/1187415?