# SwiftUI in a Notification Content Extension?

Tags: ios, swiftui

Can a SwiftUI view be used in a Notification Content Extension? The Xcode template only offers a view controller, could this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to embed a SwiftUI view in the `UIViewController` using `UIHostingController`. There are more extensive answers here ([Include SwiftUI views in existing UIKit application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433826/include-swiftui-views-in-existing-uikit-application)), but here's a short version using the Xcode template for `UNNotificationContentExtension` as a base:

```
class NotificationViewController: UIViewController, UNNotificationContentExtension {
    @IBOutlet var container: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView())
        addChild(childView)
        childView.view.frame = container.bounds
        container.addSubview(childView.view)
        childView.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
    
    func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Has this changed at WWDC 2021?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of

Comment: There's `UNNotificationContentProviding` but there's no documentation about it, I wonder if this could be it: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationcontentproviding

Comment: That doesn't look related to SwiftUI at all.

Comment: Hi @jnpdx , if i create an horizontal progress bar in my swiftui view and update it every seconds, that updates in my local notification?

Comment: Sorry — I don’t understand. If you have an additional question, I suggest you make a new post.

Comment: @jnpdx, i want to use this notification content extension in swiftui project, with your answer we can add swiftui view to story board, but how can i call this story board view in my swiftui app?

Comment: Know i add my swiftui view in UIHostingController but that gives error can not find my view in scope, what should i do?

Comment: Start a new question and include the relevant code. This isn’t a good conversation to have in the comment section.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I do it using AutoLayout rules.

```
...
var hostingView: UIHostingController<NotificationView>!
...

func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
  let notificationView = NotificationView()
  hostingView = UIHostingController(rootView: notificationView)
  
  self.view.addSubview(hostingView.view)
  hostingView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  
  hostingView.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
  hostingView.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
  hostingView.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
  hostingView.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

http://brunowernimont.me/howtos/2021-06-21-embed-swiftui-view-in-notification-content-extension

https://github.com/brunow/SwiftUILocalNotification