# Open swiftUI view from UIKit code for rightBarItem

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, hyperlink, uikit

This is code of UIKit File.I want to open view which is editButtonCustomizeView and written in swiftUI. How can I take action of this button which navigates to swiftUI

> override func viewDidLoad() {   super.viewDidLoad()
>
> let editButton   = UIBarButtonItem(image: editImage,  style: .Plain,
> target: self, action: editButtonCustomizeView())
>
> }

Right now getting error is "Cannot convert value of type 'editButtonCustomizeView' to expected argument type 'Selector?' "

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433826/include-swiftui-views-in-existing-uikit-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the action expects a selector to point to what action is to be called when the button is tapped so you can't pass a view.

If you want to show a SwiftUI view when that button is tapped you have to first add a action to show the viewcontroller, then create the action to show the viewcontroller and lastly add you SwiftUI view in a viewcontroller so it can be used in UIKit.

**Adding the action to the button:**

```
let editButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: editImage, style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(showSwiftUIView))
```

**Then the action to show the view:**

```
@objc func showSwiftUIView(sender: UIControl) {
   let vc = editButtonCustomizeVC()
   present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

**And lastly turn your view to a ViewController:**

```
final class editButtonCustomizeVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: editButtonCustomizeView())
        addChild(childView)
        childView.view.frame = view.bounds
        view.addSubview(childView.view)
        childView.didMove(toParent: self)
        
    }

}
```

Comment: getting error in showSwiftUIView method

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'editButtonCustomizeVC()' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'