# How can I use my SwiftUI components in my UIKit project?

Tags: swiftui, uikit

I started working in UIKit at first and started to work on SwiftUI due to requirement.
Now I have a framework with my custom components like button, textfield etc..
I want to make my SwiftUI framework to work in UIKit as well. How can I do that?

I created a dummy framework with few components and added that to a UIKit project and created a workspace as it asked me to do it. I'm expecting to list my components in a tableview one by one.
Also I have a factory class in my SwiftUI framework which returns my components based on passed identifier.

```
public class ComponentFactory {
    var identifier: String
    public static let shared = ComponentFactory(identifier: "")
    
    public init (identifier: String) {
        self.identifier = identifier
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder public func createView(identifier: String) -> some View {
        switch identifier {
        case "txt":
            TextComponent()
        case "btn":
            ButtonComponent(action: {})
        case "img":
            ImageComponent()
        default:
            Text("Hey, check identifier")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include SwiftUI views in existing UIKit application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433826/include-swiftui-views-in-existing-uikit-application)

Comment: The author's asking the opposite. @jnpdx "Interfacing with SwiftUI"

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/using_swiftui_with_uikit

Answer (score 1):

To use SwiftUI components in a UIKit project, you can make use of `UIHostingController` and `UIViewRepresentable` to bridge between SwiftUI and UIKit. Below is an example of how you might integrate your SwiftUI components into a UIKit project.

Let's assume you have SwiftUI components like `TextComponent`, `ButtonComponent`, and `ImageComponent`. You need to create corresponding `UIViewRepresentable` wrappers for each SwiftUI component. Here is an example for the `TextComponent`:

```
struct TextComponentRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return UIHostingController(rootView: TextComponent())
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        // Update the view if needed
    }
}
```

Now, modify your `ComponentFactory` to provide representable views instead of directly returning SwiftUI views:

```
public class ComponentFactory {
    var identifier: String

    public static let shared = ComponentFactory(identifier: "")

    public init(identifier: String) {
        self.identifier = identifier
    }

        @ViewBuilder public func createView(identifier: String) -> some View {
            switch identifier {
            case "txt":
                TextComponentRepresentable()
            case "btn":
                ButtonComponentRepresentable()
            case "img":
                ImageComponentRepresentable()
            default:
                Text("Hey, check identifier")
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, in your UIKit project, you can use the `createView` method from `ComponentFactory` to get a SwiftUI component and then use it in a `UIHostingController`:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let factory = ComponentFactory.shared
        let hostedView = UIHostingController(rootView: factory.createView(identifier: "txt"))
        
        addChild(hostedView)
        view.addSubview(hostedView.view)
        hostedView.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}
```