# How to use SwiftUI in framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, swiftui, xcodebuild

I'm using `SwiftUI` inside my binary framework, I added `SwiftUI.framework` as Optional in `Embedded Binaries` and use `@available` so it compiles just fine with deployment target iOS 9.
However I cannot use it with `xcodebuild`, my commands :

```
xcodebuild clean archive \
    -project "${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj" \
    -scheme ${1} \
    -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} \
    -destination "${2}" \
    -archivePath "${3}" \
    SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
    OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}/DependentBuilds" \
    BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES | xcpretty
```

error message:

> use of undeclared type 'View'
>
> use of unresolved identifier 'UIHostingController'

P/s: `-weak_framework SwiftUI` in **Other Linker Flags** also didn't work

Answer (score 2):

`SwiftUI` doesn't have 32 bit header, so adding architecture flag where the error is fix the issue

```
#if (arch(x86_64) || arch(arm64))
//...
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap SwiftUI related code in `#if canImport(SwiftUI) && canImport(Combine)` statements. See [example](https://github.com/ruuvi/com.ruuvi.station.ios/blob/dev/station/Classes/Presentation/Modules/Settings/Submodules/Daemons/View/SwiftUI/DaemonsEnvironmentObject.swift).

Comment: Please try to give a concrete example and not links. your link is broken and not helpful at the moment.

Comment: The rescued link is https://github.com/ruuvi/com.ruuvi.station.ios/blob/44c931e25ae7664168ff4ffeede1c049bb241c15/station/Classes/Presentation/Modules/Settings/Submodules/Daemons/View/SwiftUI/DaemonsEnvironmentObject.swift

Comment: The code sample is so short though, you should probably also just copy it into your answer.