# dyld: Library not loaded SwiftUI when app runs on iOS 12 using @available(iOS 13.0, *)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I decided to implement a few views using SwiftUI in my app. The app is backward compatible with iOS 12.

Everything works perfectly until I run it on an iOS 12 device. The app crashes immediately and the warning I get says SwiftUI cannot be loaded.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Reason: image not found
```

I'm using @available(iOS 13.0, *) in all the correct places and there are no compiler warnings and the app runs perfectly on iOS 13

How can I get this to work for iOS 12?

Comment: You linked the framework to your project? I guess it's marked as "Required" and not Weak or optional. On an old version https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkekO.png found there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4

Comment: @Larme I found it was a known issue and posted an answer to solve this

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Turns out this is a known issue and apple introduced a new build setting flag to handle it

> Apps containing SwiftUI inside a Swift package might not run on
> versions of iOS earlier than iOS 13. (53706729)
>
> Workaround:
>
> When back-deploying to an OS which doesn't contain the SwiftUI framework,
> add the -weak_framework SwiftUI flag to the Other Linker Flags setting
> in the Build Settings tab. See Frameworks and Weak Linking for more
> information on weak linking a framework. This workaround doesn't apply
> when using dynamically linked Swift packages which import SwiftUI.

Adding  `-weak_framework SwiftUI` to `Other Linker Flags` fixed my issue

Comment: Note that `-weak_framework` and `SwiftUI` should be added as two separate entries in the Other Linker Flags list. The way the documentation and this post are written, it looks like one flag, but Xcode won't accept that.

Comment: Absolute life saver! Thank you so much.

Comment: In my case, our app started to crash on iOS 12 after upgrading from Xcode 15.0.1 to Xcode 15.1, in which Apple did some changes to the linker. So glad to find this 5-year-old post that still solve the 2024 problem.

Answer (score 19):

You can also mark SwiftUI.framwerk as optional in Build Phases. Detailed Instruction below.

1. Select your project file in the Xcode navigator.
2. Select your app target (or whichever target you're using SwiftUI from).
3. Select the “Build Phases” tab, then the “Link Binary With Libraries” section.
4. Click the + button under the list that appears.
5. Type “SwiftUI” into the search field of the popup sheet, select
   “SwiftUI.framework,” and click “Add.”
6. On the new row in the table, click the “Required” popup button in the last column. Change the
   value to “Optional.”

Comment: Thank you - I ve been trawling around for ages. Worked for me.

Comment: This is the solution for runtime crashes and the other solves the problem during the build phase, I personally did both just to be safe and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score -7):

So sorry, but I don't think SwiftUI Will work on older versions then iOS 13. Found this stack link if you want more details [Is SwiftUI backwards-compatible with iOS 12.x and older?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433305/is-swiftui-backwards-compatible-with-ios-12-x-and-older)

Comment: Yes, but you would be able to use @available to dictate what is being used by iOS 13 or not