# Have a version compatible with iOS 11 - iO12 and another with iOS13 (swiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

I have my app approved in the appstore:

- Version 1 made with SwiftUI for iOS13 ↑
- Version 2 made with Storyboard for iOS11 - iOS13
- Version 3 made with with SwiftUI for iOS13 ↑ (Future versions all with swiftUI)

What I need is that for older devices (with iOS12 below allow them to download version 2)

When I uploaded version 2, the software with iOS12 - iOS12 could download it, but when I upload version 3 it can no longer be downloaded, it forces you to have iOS13.

So how can I do to have a version of my mod app for people who have devices with iO12 and earlier a compatible version appears and those who have iOS13 can download the latest version.

If I send the version for iOS 11 - iOS 12 as a new app, can you approve it?

Comment: You can only have one active version in the store. So if you want older devices to have access to the app you would need to use your Version 2.  You can use SwiftUI code in the same project just would need to add `@available(iOS 13.0, *)` to files that are using SwiftUI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is SwiftUI backwards-compatible with iOS 12.x and older?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433305/is-swiftui-backwards-compatible-with-ios-12-x-and-older)

Answer (score 0):

The most common practice I've seen is to make your current app only support iOS 13, but release a new version for older OS's called `My App - Legacy Edition` or something in that vein. It allows all your existing customers to continue with the version they have installed, but also lets slow upgraders find your app in the App Store. Hope that helps!